# how to scraping a site using php

Tags: php, web-scraping

I'm getting the content of the site using this following code

```
function get_content($url){
    $content = @file_get_contents($url);
    if( empty($content) ){
      $content = get_url_contents($url);
    }
    return $content;
}

function get_url_contents($url){
    $crl = curl_init();
    $timeout = 90;
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}

$url = "http://www.site.com";
$html = get_content($url);
echo $html;
```

Everything is ok, but I need to get for example all my div elements or the title of the page or all my images.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use a HTML Parsing library. While many of them exist, I have personally used [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and had a good experience. It uses JQuery style selectors making it easy to learn.

Some code samples:

To get title of page:

```
$html = str_get_html($html);
$title = $html->find('title',0);
echo $title->plaintext;
```

For all div elements:

```
$html = str_get_html($html);
$divs = $html->find('div');

foreach($divs as $div) {
   // do something;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument)

eg:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    echo $div->nodeValue. PHP_EOL;
}
```